# Can/Should I use the output of a log-linear model as the predictors in a logistic regression model?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

I have a data set with both continuous and categorical variables.  In the end I want to build a logistic regression model to calculate the probability of a response dichotomous variable.

Is it acceptable, or even a good idea, to apply a log linear model to the categorical variables in the model to test their interactions, and then use the indicated interactions as predictors in the logistic model?

Example in R:

Columns in df: CategoricalA, CategoricalB, CategoricalC, CategoricalD, CategoricalE, ContinuousA, ContinuousB, ResponseA

```
library(MASS)

#Isolate categorical variables in new data frame
catdf <- df[,c("CategoricalA","CategoricalB","CategoricalC", "CategoricalD", "CategoricalE")]

#Create cross table
crosstable <- table(catdf)

#build log-lin model
model <- loglm(formula = ~ CategoricalA * CategoricalB * CategoricalC * CategoricalD * CategoricalE, data = crosstable)

#Use step() to build better model
automodel <- step(object = model, direction = "backward")
```

Then build a logistic regresion using the output of `automodel`and the values of ContinuousA and ContinuousB in order to predict ResponseA (which is binary).

My hunch is that this is not ok, but I cant find the answer definitively one way or the other.

Comment: Probably stats.stackexchange.com is a better forum for this question.

Comment: Agree with Robert but would add that both models are estimated on a  log scale and should provide similar answers with respect to "significance".  As pointed out in the MASS documentation, you could use ordinary `glm` to build a loglinear model and then `predict.glm` to do it all within one framework.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. You can use any information in the model that will be available in out-of-time or 'production' run of the model. Whether this information is good, powerful, significant, etc. is a different question.
The logic is that a model can have any type of RHS variable, be it categorical, continuous, logical, etc. Furthermore, you can combine RHS variables to create one RHS variable and also apply transformations. The log linear model of categorical is nothing by a transformed linear combination of raw variables (that happen to be categorical). This method would not be violating any particular modeling framework.